# How to generate an automatic student id number?

Tags: java, sql

I'm creating a system for the school that needs to have an automatic generation of Student ID Number that have a format like this xxxx-xxxx, I need to create in java netbeans. The student ID Number needs to be unique and it's primary key.

Comment: Please add your efforts

Comment: You say you need to create the id number in Java but go on to say that it needs to be a primary key which implies that you are interfacing with a relational database system.  Can you explain your model and requirements with greater clarity?  The issue of when to generate an entity's identity has no one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: Why four digits plus hyphen plus four digits? What meaning is intended by the various digits? If this were simply a sequence number, we would not need the hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you let the database generate the key as a numeric value, and then format it in your program.

Say you have an autogenerated primary key from your database, and the generated key is 18435876, you can format it in java to be "1843-5876".

Answer (score 0):

You could first create `id` field in database with auto increment option, then format it in java

```
Integer id = 12345678; //id get from database
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(id.toString());
str.insert(str.length() - 4, '-');
System.out.println(str);
```

If only in java application, you can use AtomicInteger and convert it to string then format as above code
(see more at https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/atomic/atomicinteger/java-atomicinteger-example/, but this method is not recommended because if the system down, the AtomicInteger value will reset to initial value)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

Example: you can use Snowflake generate a unique id, if you got the id, you can do anything!

Answer (score 0):

Let the auto-generated Primary key be: 45454545.Now all you have to do is format it in java.

For formatting you can use `.format()` or `.substring()` or `StringBuilder()`.

```
        String PK = "45454545";


        String output =  String.format("%1$s-%2$s", PK.substring(0,4), 
        PK.substring(4));
```

Or

```
String output =PK.substring(0,4) + "-" + PK.substring(4);
```

Or

```
String output = new StringBuilder(PK).insert(4, '-').toString();
```